# SQL syntax error using prepared statements and variables

Tags: mysql

I have three stored procedures for three different ERPs making almost exactly the same operations, so I decided to make just one, and use parameters. Some of the field names change depending on the parameters, so I set them in variables. Then I am using prepared statements to make it work.

A working update that does not use prepared statements is as follows:

```
update lt_erp_barcodes
set barcode_list = concat(',', curr_barcode, barcode_list)
where cod_navision = curr_erp_code;
```

It updates the current barcode_list adding curr_barcode at the beggining of the list, and adding also a comma. (,curr_barcode,the rest of the list,)

My approach to make it work with prepared statement is:

```
set @erp_code_field_name = "cod_navision";
set @curr_erp_code = '12345';
set @curr_barcode = '123123123';
set @q1 = concat('update lt_erp_barcodes
                  set barcode_list = (\',\'', @curr_barcode, ' barcode_list)
                   where ', @erp_code_field_name, ' = ', @curr_erp_code);
prepare update_barcode_list from @q1;
execute update_barcode_list;
```

But when I call to `prepare` the following error is raised:

> 0 228 10:30:17    prepare update_barcode_list from @q1    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '123123123 barcode_list
>                       where cod_navision = 12345' at line 2   0.047 sec

How could I make the second block of code work the same as the first one?
Thanks

Comment: Can you print the generated sql statement?

Comment: Actually you can use double quote instead of single quote around the string if you need it to have a single quote i.e. concat("'",@variable,"'"); something like that.

Comment: I think you're a little confused about how prepared statements are supposed to work (and how they protect you from SQL injection). In the end, the way you're *attempting to* do this means you've not added any protection. You are still just concatenating SQL queries together.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I need prepared statements because I need table fields names to be inside variables. Thanks for your advice about SQL Injection.

Comment: In which case, you should combine the two. Use parameters where you can, such as where `curr_barcode` and `curr_erp_code` are used, and only use concatenation for `erp_code_field_name`. You need to be *very* careful, however, that the injected column name is never controlled by the end-user.

Comment: As an example of the issues you face if you don't properly handle user input, consider what `q1` becomes if someone enters a new barcode as `') --`. You run your query and now every entry in `lt_erp_barcodes` has the same barcode set in `barcode_list`.

Comment: I take good note, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your answers. I finally achieved it as follows:

```
set @q1 = concat('update lt_main_barcodes_v2
              set barcode_list = concat(\',', @curr_barcode, '\', barcode_list)
               where ', @erp_code_field_name, ' = ', @curr_erp_code);
```

I corrected syntax errors (thanks James) and added another concat(). Now, MySQL understands barcode_list is a field. Selecting @q1 gives brings the following output:

```
update lt_erp_barcodes
set barcode_list = concat(',123123123', barcode_list)
where cod_navision = 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is generating non legal SQL in the @Q1 variable:

```
DELIMITER $

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procTest$

CREATE PROCEDURE procTest()
BEGIN

    set @erp_code_field_name := "cod_navision";
    set @curr_erp_code := '12345';
    set @curr_barcode := '123123123';
    set @q1 := concat('update lt_erp_barcodes
                      set barcode_list = (\',\'', @curr_barcode, ' barcode_list)
                       where ', @erp_code_field_name, ' = ', @curr_erp_code);

    SELECT @q1;                       

    prepare update_barcode_list from @q1;
    execute update_barcode_list;

END$

DELIMITER ;

CALL procTest();
```

See the result here:

```
update lt_erp_barcodes
                      set barcode_list = (','123123123 barcode_list)
                       where cod_navision = 12345
```

What is the actual result you are trying to achieve? Let me know if you still can't solve this,

James

Answer (score 0):

You may need to take off the ' barcode_list' from your @q1

```
set @q1 = concat('update lt_erp_barcodes
                  set barcode_list = (\',\'', @curr_barcode, ') where ',
                  @erp_code_field_name, ' = ', @curr_erp_code);
```

Anyway, you should change it as @Phylogenesis told you in its comment.